# Should I mix variable and constant data inside a react state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, state

I'm trying to think about the data structure of my app and came into an interesting question:

I have some data that will be defined inside my code (without fetching) and won't change during the lifecycle of my app. Let's say that this data is a list of objects representing `streets`, that have properties such as `name`, `size` etc that are permanent.

But related to each `street` there are, for example, `number of houses` inside it, and it might change.

Is it better to use `number of houses` as a property and keep the entire `streets` list inside the app state, or have only a list of `number of houses` in the app state and associate them with `streets` based on indexes/keys?

Sorry, I couldn't figure out a better generical example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for your case is to use **[useReducer](https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer)** hook which is efficient for states in format of Array/Object. So for the streets constant you can declare it in a separate file (consts.js for example) so you can reuse it in multiple components if needed then import it to your component where you want to handle the **number of houses**:

```
import { STREETS } from "consts";


const Actions = {
  ADD_HOUSE: 'ADD_HOUSE',
  REMOVE_HOUSE: 'REMOVE_HOUSE',
  UPDATE_HOUSES: 'UPDATE_HOUSES'
  RESET: 'RESET'
};
  
const initialState = { 
    streets: STREETS
}
  
function reducer(state, {type, payload}) {
    switch(type){
      case Actions.ADD_HOUSE:{
        //You logic
      }
      ...
    }
}
function YourComponent() {
  const [{ streets }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
...
}
```

NOTE: It's better to separate the reducer logic from your component you can use another file called ***reducer.js*** for example then export ***Actions, initialState, reducer func***.

Comment: Nice, but what about the `name` of the streets? Should I put them in the initial state, or in a new `const` array and correlate them by indices?

Comment: Just pass it to streets in initial state instead of empty array (the answer updated).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if maybe that could cost a bit of perfomance. What do you think?

Comment: In terms of performance useReducer and useState produce the same behavior in the Component so it will render when the state value changed, the main difference between those hooks is useReducer provides more predictable state transitions than useState which becomes more important when you have a complex state and state changes so you need to have one place to manage state.